# Angular ui.router only load one file, can't look elsewhere for templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I think I just don't understand something but here's my case : 
I'm using a view engine in my "app.js" file

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Using **ui-router**, I'm currently declaring my states like this :

```
.state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      })
```

This state apparently look into my `index.ejs` file for something like:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html"> ...</script>
```

My "index.ejs" file is something like that:

```
<html>
 <body ng-app="PerformManagement" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div >
      <!-- On appelle le template-->
    <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">...</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/risks.html" ng-controller="RisksCtrl">...</script>
```

It works this way but I want to slice my **index.ejs** into different files because it start getting too big for me to work on properly.
I call my template when changing state by this way, in index.ejs :

```
<div class="container">
    <div >
      <!--Template called-->
      <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I've created files like "home.html" where I put my html code, and I want my templateUrl load it. But passing something like `templateUrl: 'home.html'` doesn't work at all. I've tried to put my "home.html" in many places but still can't understand why it doesn't work.
I'm pretty new working on Angular and Node so I think I've missed something.
I followed this tutorial https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack/

I'm quite lost at the moment so if anybody could find a nice way to do that, I'll really appreciate.

Comment: I don't know how to use mean, but I use ui-router with angular. First its better to omit the slash in front of the templateUrl name : 'home.html'. Second, I use <ui-view></ui-view> to alternate between states

Comment: I use <ui-view></ui-view> too to display my templates & altern between states. But still want to take my template from another file, not just index.ejs and I don't understand why.

Comment: When you load the index file, there is no state called. So it's not the `home` state right? You won't get the home template in the ui-view until you call the home state. You can however tell your app to call the `home` state when you initially load the index file. Is that what you want?

Comment: No, what you're saying is already done with $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home'); I think. The problem is that my "index.ejs" is something like a default file as I see. In this file, I have my templates as I explained before, but I just want to write these templates in a another file. The problem is that I'm not able to call them from another file when using templateUrl. I want to be able to call a template from another location, but for now, it seems like it's only able to find template written inside index file.

Comment: You mean the script tags that do reference to the templates? And if you keep there tags in index file it works? But when you put somewhere else it doesn't?

Comment: Yes, between the script tags, I write my code for a template. And if I try to move this script tag in another file, It can't find it, even if I change the path in templateUrl:"/home.html" for something like templateUrl: "views/template/home.html".

Comment: I suggest that you use component. I prepared an example for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/VJFaR1OiYeZuaJIu8PLc?p=preview Using component will allow you to use resolve and bindings later on to inject data

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll try this in few minutes.